# Compare JavaScript Array of Objects to Get Min / Max

Tags: javascript, arrays, compare, array-of-dict

I have an array of objects and I want to compare those objects on a specific object property. Here's my array:

```
var myArray = [
    {"ID": 1, "Cost": 200},
    {"ID": 2, "Cost": 1000},
    {"ID": 3, "Cost": 50},
    {"ID": 4, "Cost": 500}
]
```

I'd like to zero in on the "cost" specifically and a get a min and maximum value. I realize I can just grab the cost values and push them off into a javascript array and then run the [Fast JavaScript Max/Min](http://ejohn.org/blog/fast-javascript-maxmin/).

However is there an easier way to do this by bypassing the array step in the middle and going off the objects properties (in this case "Cost") directly?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

One way is to loop through all elements and compare it to the highest/lowest value.

*(Creating an array, invoking array methods is overkill for this simple operation).*

```
 // There's no real number bigger than plus Infinity
var lowest = Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
var highest = Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;
var tmp;
for (var i=myArray.length-1; i>=0; i--) {
    tmp = myArray[i].Cost;
    if (tmp < lowest) lowest = tmp;
    if (tmp > highest) highest = tmp;
}
console.log(highest, lowest);
```

Comment: This makes sense, I've been stuck with thinking about comparing data inside the array to each other instead of an external high/low number.

Comment: The only thing I would change is setting lowest and highest is a bit redundant. I would rather loop one less time and set `lowest=highest=myArray[0]` and then start the loop at 1.

Comment: @32bitkid Good point. should be `myArray[0].Cost`, though. But, if there's no first element, an error will be thrown. So, an additional check is needed, possibly undoing the small performance boost.

Comment: I came here because I want the object itself returned. Not the lowest value, which was easy. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Wilt Yes, maintain another variable that gets updated when you've found a lowest value, i.e. `var lowestObject; for (...)` and `if (tmp < lowest) { lowestObject = myArray[i]; lowest = tmp; }`

Comment: I'd argue creating temp variables and a for loop is overkill. The array is already created. See the top voted solution using reduce.

Comment: If you're looking for an ES6 method that is a one liner keep going down. It's in a comment below. Copied here. `Math.min(...myArray.map(o => o.Cost))`

Comment: I think using `sort` method will provide min at the first position and max at the last position. `myArray.sort((a, b) => a.Cost - b.Cost);`

Comment: This answer is very old, before ECMAScript 2015 (ES6) went out. Was right at the time, but now [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31844649/424498) is a better option.

Answer (score 280):

[`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) is good for stuff like this:  to perform aggregate operations (like min, max, avg, etc.) on an array, and return a single result:

```
myArray.reduce(function(prev, curr) {
    return prev.Cost < curr.Cost ? prev : curr;
});
```

...or you can define that inner function with ES6 function syntax:

```
myArray.reduce((prev, curr) => prev.Cost < curr.Cost ? prev : curr);
```

If you want to be cute you can attach this to the Array prototype:

```
Array.prototype.hasMin = function(attrib) {
    return (this.length && this.reduce(function(prev, curr){ 
        return prev[attrib] < curr[attrib] ? prev : curr; 
    })) || null;
 }
```

Now you can just say:

```
myArray.hasMin('ID')  // result:  {"ID": 1, "Cost": 200}
myArray.hasMin('Cost')    // result: {"ID": 3, "Cost": 50}
myEmptyArray.hasMin('ID')   // result: null
```

Please note that if you intend to use this, it doesn't have full checks for every situation.  If you pass in an array of primitive types, it will fail.  If you check for a property that doesn't exist, or if not all the objects contain that property, you will get the last element.  This version is a little more bulky, but has those checks:

```
Array.prototype.hasMin = function(attrib) {
    const checker = (o, i) => typeof(o) === 'object' && o[i]
    return (this.length && this.reduce(function(prev, curr){
        const prevOk = checker(prev, attrib);
        const currOk = checker(curr, attrib);
        if (!prevOk && !currOk) return {};
        if (!prevOk) return curr;
        if (!currOk) return prev;
        return prev[attrib] < curr[attrib] ? prev : curr; 
    })) || null;
 }
```

Comment: Best answer in my opinion. It doesn't modify the array and its far more concise than the answer that says "Creating an array, invoking array methods is overkill for this simple operation"

Comment: This is the absolute best answer for performance of large datasets (30+ columns / 100k rows).

Comment: There is a missing parenthesis in the first part.

Comment: Just wondering, when reduce checks the first element of the array won't `prev.Cost` be undefined? Or does it initiate as 0?

Comment: addendum: sorry, just read [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

short answer: index starts at 1 if no initial value provided when using reduce

Comment: Yes - that's an important point:  if you have a reduce that uses an accumulator that's a different type than the elements of the original array, it's really important to provide an initial value, otherwise the accumulator will start with the wrong type.

Comment: This solution will throw exception if the array is empty.

Comment: Good point @Saheb.  I just edited so it will return null in that case.

Comment: I also added some checks for other inputs that could cause issues, like non-objects, or if that property was missing from some of the objects.  Ultimately it's getting a little heavy-handed for most cases I think.

Comment: if you prefer not to alter the prototype, you can use `call` or `apply` as in `hasMin.call(myArray, 'Cost')`.

Answer (score 63):

Using `Math.min` and `Math.max`:

```js
var myArray = [
    { id: 1, cost: 200},
    { id: 2, cost: 1000},
    { id: 3, cost: 50},
    { id: 4, cost: 500}
]


var min = Math.min(...myArray.map(item => item.cost));
var max = Math.max(...myArray.map(item => item.cost));

console.log("min: " + min);
console.log("max: " + max);
```

Comment: I know it must be to late to ask but why do we need the spread operator like you did for ```myArray.map()``` I would appreciate the answer

Comment: Because the function `Math.max` takes multiple parameters and not an array. The spread operator will transform the array into a "list" of parameters. e.g.: `Math.max(...[1,5,9])` is the equivalent of `Math.max(1, 5, 9)`. Without the spread operator, `Math.max(myArray)` will return NaN (not a number) since the function expects multiple number parameters. I hope it is not to late to reply @NtshemboHlongwane ;)

Answer (score 36):

Use [`sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort), if you don't care about the array being modified.

```
myArray.sort(function (a, b) {
    return a.Cost - b.Cost
})

var min = myArray[0],
    max = myArray[myArray.length - 1]
```

Comment: a full sort isn't the fastest way to find min/max but i guess it'll work.

Comment: Just be aware that this will modify `myArray`, which may not be expected.

Comment: Sorting an array is slower than traversing it. Sort complexity: `O(nlog(n))`, traversing an array: `O(n)`

Answer (score 31):

Use `Math` functions and pluck out the values you want with `map`.

Here is the jsbin:

https://jsbin.com/necosu/1/edit?js,console

```
var myArray = [{
    "ID": 1,
    "Cost": 200
  }, {
    "ID": 2,
    "Cost": 1000
  }, {
    "ID": 3,
    "Cost": 50
  }, {
    "ID": 4,
    "Cost": 500
  }],

  min = Math.min.apply(null, myArray.map(function(item) {
    return item.Cost;
  })),
  max = Math.max.apply(null, myArray.map(function(item) {
    return item.Cost;
  }));

console.log('min', min);//50
console.log('max', max);//1000
```

UPDATE:

If you want to use ES6:

```
var min = Math.min.apply(null, myArray.map(item => item.Cost)),
    max = Math.max.apply(null, myArray.map(item => item.Cost));
```

Comment: In ES6 using Spread Operator, we no longer need `apply`. Simply say - 

`Math.min(...myArray.map(o => o.Cost))` for finding the minimum and 

`Math.max(...myArray.map(o => o.Cost))` for finding the maximum.

Answer (score 17):

Try (`a` is array, `f` is field to compare)

```
let max= (a,f)=> a.reduce((m,x)=> m[f]>x[f] ? m:x);
let min= (a,f)=> a.reduce((m,x)=> m[f]<x[f] ? m:x);
```

```js
let max= (a,f)=> a.reduce((m,x)=> m[f]>x[f] ? m:x);
let min= (a,f)=> a.reduce((m,x)=> m[f]<x[f] ? m:x);

// TEST

var myArray = [
    {"ID": 1, "Cost": 200},
    {"ID": 2, "Cost": 1000},
    {"ID": 3, "Cost": 50},
    {"ID": 4, "Cost": 500}
]

console.log('Max Cost', max(myArray, 'Cost'));
console.log('Min Cost', min(myArray, 'Cost'));

console.log('Max ID', max(myArray, 'ID'));
console.log('Min ID', min(myArray, 'ID'));
```

Comment: Love this answer, so compact and easy to use.

Comment: I +1 what Dean said and feel it's VERY quickly to reason about in a glance.

Answer (score 16):

I think [Rob W's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8864464/3303195) is really the right one (+1), but just for fun: if you wanted to be "clever", you *could* do something like this:

```
var myArray = 
[
    {"ID": 1, "Cost": 200},
    {"ID": 2, "Cost": 1000},
    {"ID": 3, "Cost": 50},
    {"ID": 4, "Cost": 500}
]

function finder(cmp, arr, attr) {
    var val = arr[0][attr];
    for(var i=1;i<arr.length;i++) {
        val = cmp(val, arr[i][attr])
    }
    return val;
}

alert(finder(Math.max, myArray, "Cost"));
alert(finder(Math.min, myArray, "Cost"));
```

or if you had a deeply nested structure, you could get a little more functional and do the following:

```
var myArray = 
[
    {"ID": 1, "Cost": { "Wholesale":200, Retail: 250 }},
    {"ID": 2, "Cost": { "Wholesale":1000, Retail: 1010 }},
    {"ID": 3, "Cost": { "Wholesale":50, Retail: 300 }},
    {"ID": 4, "Cost": { "Wholesale":500, Retail: 1050 }}
]

function finder(cmp, arr, getter) {
    var val = getter(arr[0]);
    for(var i=1;i<arr.length;i++) {
        val = cmp(val, getter(arr[i]))
    }
    return val;
}

alert(finder(Math.max, myArray, function(x) { return x.Cost.Wholesale; }));
alert(finder(Math.min, myArray, function(x) { return x.Cost.Retail; }));
```

These could easily be curried into more useful/specific forms.

Comment: I have benchmarked our solutions: http://jsperf.com/comparison-of-numbers. After optimizing your code (see the benchmark), the performance of both methods are similar. Without optimization, my method is 14x faster.

Comment: @RoBW oh I would totally expect your version to be *way* faster, I was just providing an alternate architectural implementation. :)

Comment: @32bitkid I expected the same, but surprisongly, the method is almost as fast (after optimizing), as seen at test case 3 of the benchmark.

Comment: @RobW i agree, I would not have expected that. I'm intrigued. :) Goes to show that you should always benchmark rather than assume.

Comment: @RobW Just to be clear though, I think with more browser results, your implementation would consistently beat either the unoptimized and optimized versions.

Comment: @32bitkid Using an array with **1000 keys**, your method (optimized) is **20% faster in Firefox 9! http://jsperf.com/comparison-of-numbers/3**. (but 81% slower in Chromium 17 :p).

Answer (score 9):

for Max

```
Math.max.apply(Math, myArray.map(a => a.Cost));
```

for min

```
Math.min.apply(Math, myArray.map(a => a.Cost));
```

Answer (score 7):

This can be achieved with lodash's `minBy` and `maxBy` functions.

**Lodash's `minBy` and `maxBy` documentation**

> `_.minBy(array, [iteratee=_.identity])`
>
> `_.maxBy(array, [iteratee=_.identity])`
>
> These methods accept an iteratee which is invoked for each element in
>   array to generate the criterion by which the value is ranked. The
>   iteratee is invoked with one argument: (value).

## Solution

```js
var myArray = [
    {"ID": 1, "Cost": 200},
    {"ID": 2, "Cost": 1000},
    {"ID": 3, "Cost": 50},
    {"ID": 4, "Cost": 500}
]

const minimumCostItem = _.minBy(myArray, "Cost");

console.log("Minimum cost item: ", minimumCostItem);

// Getting the maximum using a functional iteratee
const maximumCostItem = _.maxBy(myArray, function(entry) {
  return entry["Cost"];
});

console.log("Maximum cost item: ", maximumCostItem);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 5):

Using [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), you can plug in comparator functions to determine the min, max, etc. item in an array.

```js
var items = [
  { name : 'Apple',  count : 3  },
  { name : 'Banana', count : 10 },
  { name : 'Orange', count : 2  },
  { name : 'Mango',  count : 8  }
];

function findBy(arr, key, comparatorFn) {
  return arr.reduce(function(prev, curr, index, arr) { 
    return comparatorFn.call(arr, prev[key], curr[key]) ? prev : curr; 
  });
}

function minComp(prev, curr) {
  return prev < curr;
}

function maxComp(prev, curr) {
  return prev > curr;
}

document.body.innerHTML  = 'Min: ' + findBy(items, 'count', minComp).name + '<br />';
document.body.innerHTML += 'Max: ' + findBy(items, 'count', maxComp).name;
```

Answer (score 5):

For a concise, modern solution, one can perform a [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) operation over the array, keeping track of the current minimum and maximum values, so the array is only iterated over once (which is optimal).

```
let [min, max] = myArray.reduce(([prevMin,prevMax], {Cost})=>
   [Math.min(prevMin, Cost), Math.max(prevMax, Cost)], [Infinity, -Infinity]);
```

Demo:

```js
var myArray = [
    {"ID": 1, "Cost": 200},
    {"ID": 2, "Cost": 1000},
    {"ID": 3, "Cost": 50},
    {"ID": 4, "Cost": 500}
]
let [min, max] = myArray.reduce(([prevMin,prevMax], {Cost})=>
   [Math.min(prevMin, Cost), Math.max(prevMax, Cost)], [Infinity, -Infinity]);
console.log("Min cost:", min);
console.log("Max cost:", max);
```

Answer (score 3):

This is more better solution

```
    var myArray = [
    {"ID": 1, "Cost": 200},
    {"ID": 2, "Cost": 1000},
    {"ID": 3, "Cost": 50},
    {"ID": 4, "Cost": 500}
    ]
    var lowestNumber = myArray[0].Cost;
    var highestNumber = myArray[0].Cost;

    myArray.forEach(function (keyValue, index, myArray) {
      if(index > 0) {
        if(keyValue.Cost < lowestNumber){
          lowestNumber = keyValue.Cost;
        }
        if(keyValue.Cost > highestNumber) {
          highestNumber = keyValue.Cost;
        }
      }
    });
    console.log('lowest number' , lowestNumber);
    console.log('highest Number' , highestNumber);
```

Answer (score 3):

Adding onto Tristan Reid's answer (+ using es6), you could create a function that accepts a callback, which will contain the operator you want to be applied to the `prev` and `curr`:

```
const compare = (arr, key, callback) => arr.reduce((prev, curr) =>
    (callback(prev[key], curr[key]) ? prev : curr), {})[key];

    // remove `[key]` to return the whole object
```

Then you could simply call it using:

```
const costMin = compare(myArray, 'Cost', (a, b) => a < b);
const costMax = compare(myArray, 'Cost', (a, b) => a > b);
```

Answer (score 1):

> we can solve problem by two approach
> both method is already explained  above but the performance test was missing so completing that one

1, native java-script way
2, first sort object then it easy to get min
max from sorted obj

> i also test performance of both tow approach
>
> you can also run and test performance... Happy coding (:

```js
//first approach 

var myArray = [
    {"ID": 1, "Cost": 200},
    {"ID": 2, "Cost": 1000},
    {"ID": 3, "Cost": 50},
    {"ID": 4, "Cost": 500}
]

var t1 = performance.now();;

let max=Math.max.apply(Math, myArray.map(i=>i.Cost))

let min=Math.min.apply(Math, myArray.map(i=>i.Cost))

var t2   = performance.now();;

console.log("native fuction took " + (t2 - t1) + " milliseconds.");

console.log("max Val:"+max)
console.log("min Val:"+min)

//  Second approach:


function sortFunc (a, b) {
    return a.Cost - b.Cost
} 

var s1 = performance.now();;
sortedArray=myArray.sort(sortFunc)


var minBySortArray = sortedArray[0],
    maxBySortArray = sortedArray[myArray.length - 1]
    
var s2   = performance.now();;
 console.log("sort funciton took  " + (s2 - s1) + " milliseconds.");  
console.log("max ValBySortArray :"+max)
console.log("min Val BySortArray:"+min)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
max = totalAVG.reduce(function (a, b) { return Math.max(a, b)}, -Infinity);

min = totalAVG.reduce(function (a, b) {return Math.min(a, b)}, Infinity);
```

Answer (score -1):

Another one, similar to Kennebec's answer, but all in one line:

```
maxsort = myArray.slice(0).sort(function (a, b) { return b.ID - a.ID })[0].ID;
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use built-in Array object to use Math.max/Math.min instead:

```
var arr = [1,4,2,6,88,22,344];

var max = Math.max.apply(Math, arr);// return 344
var min = Math.min.apply(Math, arr);// return 1
```