# get single object which is having highest date from list of objects in angularJs

Tags: angularjs

New to angularJs and want to get max dated object from list of object.

I have list of customers with property CreatedOn (date)

I want to get single customer and set a property

```
customer.CurrentCustomer = true; //// when customer having max date
```

Comment: may be help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18798568/get-max-and-min-of-object-values-from-javascript-array

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between '@' and '=' in directive scope in AngularJS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14050195/what-is-the-difference-between-and-in-directive-scope-in-angularjs)

Answer (score 1):

```
customers.sort(function(a,b) { 
    return new Date(a.CreatedOn).getTime() - new Date(b.CreatedOn).getTime() 
});
```

This will sort your array in ascending order by the field CreatedOn.

Then you can pick the last item by:

```
customers[customers.length - 1]
```

and hence set the CurrentCustomer:

```
customers[customers.length - 1].CurrentCustomer = true;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use angularjs **orderByFilter**

```
function MyCtrl($scope, orderByFilter) {
$scope.customer = orderByFilter($scope. customers, 'CreatedOn')[0];
$scope.customer.CurrentCustomer=true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use libraries like Underscore, Ramda or Lodash. An example using Lodash can be found as given below and in the [Link](https://lodash.com/docs#sortBy)

```
var users = [
  { 'user': 'fred',   'age': 48 },
  { 'user': 'barney', 'age': 36 },
  { 'user': 'fred',   'age': 40 },
  { 'user': 'barney', 'age': 34 }
];

_.sortBy(users, ['user', 'age']);
```

An example using Ramda:

```
var diff = function(a, b) { return a.id > b.id; };
R.sort(diff, [
  { id: 4 },
  { id: 2 },
  { id: 7 },
  {id: 5}
]);
```