# Javascript get object from array having min value and min value is needs to find and then find object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have array of objects in object have different key so i want the object having minimum value in that array

```js
list = [{
    'id': 4,
    'name': 'nitin',
    'group': 'angularjs'
  },
  {
    'id': 1,
    'name': 'nitin',
    'group': 'angularjs'
  },
  {
    'id': 2,
    'name': 'nitin',
    'group': 'angularjs'
  },
  {
    'id': 3,
    'name': 'nitin',
    'group': 'angularjs'
  }
]
```

I tried by

```js
var minValue = Math.min.apply(Math, list.map(function (o) {
   return o.id;
}))
```

but it returns only the id not whole object then i have to make more filter for get object

is there any direct method to find object?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compare JavaScript Array of Objects to Get Min / Max](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8864430/compare-javascript-array-of-objects-to-get-min-max)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use Array `reduce` method:

```js
var list = [
{
'id':4,
'name':'nitin',
'group':'angularjs'
},
{
'id':1,
'name':'nitin',
'group':'angularjs'
},
{
'id':2,
'name':'nitin',
'group':'angularjs'
},
{
'id':3,
'name':'nitin',
'group':'angularjs'
}];

var result = list.reduce(function(res, obj) {
    return (obj.id < res.id) ? obj : res;
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 6):

Using `Array#reduce()`

```js
list = [{
    'id': 4,
    'name': 'nitin',
    'group': 'angularjs'
  },
  {
    'id': 1,
    'name': 'nitin',
    'group': 'angularjs'
  },
  {
    'id': 2,
    'name': 'nitin',
    'group': 'angularjs'
  },
  {
    'id': 3,
    'name': 'nitin',
    'group': 'angularjs'
  }
];

let min = list.reduce((prev, curr) => prev.id < curr.id ? prev : curr);

console.log(min);
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried these solutions with Array.reduce but none of them were full proof. They do not handle cases where the array is empty or only has 1 element.

Instead this worked for me:

```
const result = array.reduce(
    (prev, current) =>
      (prev?.id ?? current?.id) >= current?.id ? current : prev,
    null,
  );
```

It returns null if array is empty and handles other cases well.

Answer (score 0):

You can check for the object with the lowest id by looping through the array like so, probably not the neatest way, but a solution either way:

```
var list = [
{
'id':4,
'name':'nitin',
'group':'angularjs'
},
{
'id':1,
'name':'nitin',
'group':'angularjs'
},
{
'id':2,
'name':'nitin',
'group':'angularjs'
},
{
'id':3,
'name':'nitin',
'group':'angularjs'
}]

var tmp = list[0].id;

list.forEach(function (entry) {
    if (entry.id < tmp) {
    tmp = entry;
  }
});

console.log(tmp);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/camgssk3/

Comment: there seems to be a typo here, when you initialize tmp var you are pointing to the id not the entity, suggested fix:
 
`var tmp = list[0];

list.forEach(function (entry) {
    if (entry.id < tmp.id) {
    tmp = entry;
  }
});

console.log(tmp);`

Answer (score 0):

other option may be to filter your array as you already have min "id"

```js
var list = [
{
'id':4,
'name':'nitin',
'group':'angularjs'
},
{
'id':1,
'name':'nitin',
'group':'angularjs'
},
{
'id':2,
'name':'nitin',
'group':'angularjs'
},
{
'id':3,
'name':'nitin',
'group':'angularjs'
}];
var min = Math.min.apply(Math, list.map(function (o) {
                return o.id;
            }));
filtered = list.filter(function(elem){
  if(elem.id == min){console.log(elem);return elem;}
})
```

Comment: The question already mentioned filtering the original array based on the result of `Math.min()`, and explicitly asked for a more direct method.