# NodeJS: Array.reduce to find Min and Max in an Array of Objects

Tags: arrays, node.js, object, max, reduce

I have an array of objects that goes like:

```
test = {
  bar: [
    {p: '1',
     v: '2',
     sn: '1509007228'
    },
    {p: '34',
     v: '3',
     sn: '1509007228'
    },
    {p: '0.5',
     v: '4',
     sn: '1509007228'
    }],
  foo: [
    {p: '1',
     v: '2',
     sn: '1509007228'
    },
    {p: '34',
     v: '3',
     sn: '1509007228'
    },
    {p: '0.5',
     v: '4',
     sn: '1509007228'
    }]
}
```

And I found that function on SO that works like a charm... Even if I'm not sure exactly how since the reduce function is [supposed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce?v=b) to return an **accumulator first** and **then the current value**. I'm not sure how the accumulator is handled as it should return `undefined`, but I guess that's a question for another place and time! 
So here's the [function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8864430/compare-javascript-array-of-objects-to-get-min-max#31844649) (thanks to Tristan Reid):

```
Array.prototype.hasMin = function(attrib) {
    return this.reduce(function(prev, curr){ 
        return prev[attrib] < curr[attrib] ? prev : curr; 
    });
 }
```

When I use it on the previous object it works perfectly:

```
var blu = test.foo.hasMin('p');
```

> { p: '0.5', v: '4', sn: '1509007228' }

And the result is correct if I reverse the logic: ie. trying to find the highest value:

```
Array.prototype.hasMin = function(attrib) {
  return this.reduce(function(prev, curr) {
    return prev[attrib] > curr[attrib] ? prev : curr;
  });
};
```

I could call it then hasMax I guess... but you know, it's relatively irrelevant for now.

```
var blu = test.foo.hasMin('p');
```

> { p: '34', v: '3', sn: '1509007228' }

but when I try to use it on the actual object (much, much longer) it seems to stop on a specific value: `999.00`

[Here's the full object](http://www.filedropper.com/object_1) (I apologies for the size... I was unable to paste it here because of it (> 70,000 lines)).

And when I try the 'hasMax' function I get:

```
var bar = foo.bids.hasMin('p');
```

> { sn: '1509007228', v: '53.00000000', p: '999.00', type: 'bids' }

When the correct object for 'p'Max should be:

```
{
      sn: '1509007228',
      v: '0.15200000',
      p: '5721.32',
      type: 'bids'
    },
```

I'm not sure if there's a limitation in the `array.reduce` function that makes it impossible for this function to work on my object? 
Anyhow, thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please change your code that it looks like this:

```
return parseFloat(prev[attrib]) > parseFloat(curr[attrib]) ? prev : curr;
```

Your **p** is a string

> p: '5721.32'

so you compare strings, when you should compare numbers.

Comment: God... yet another dumb question posted on SO. Sorry guys and thanks for your help lurii!