# Get Lowest Price in Array of Objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, average, minimum

I have an array of objects called `cars` that contains search result listings. In each listing there is an attribute called `data-price`.

**Array Object Example**

```
<li xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" id="listing-ECAR-R-EY-MCOO001-EY-MCOO001" data-price="94.03"></li>
```

I'm wondering how I can get the lowest data-price value? And the average data-price value from the array of cars?

Code:

// This prints out each price value

```
cars.forEach(function(element) {
    console.log(element[0].getAttribute("data-price"));
});
```

Comment: Please post your array, not a jquery object.

Comment: your example is useless

Comment: Do you guys know how I can print more info about the array? See: http://prntscr.com/jcw41s

Comment: console.log(cars)

Comment: See: http://prntscr.com/jcw5fc ...I'm not sure the best to copy/paste entire array for you :/

Comment: You have to use some jquery in order to find out the final array, then post array to question.

Comment: Let me know if the above works...having problems with printing out entire array :(

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compare JavaScript Array of Objects to Get Min / Max](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8864430/compare-javascript-array-of-objects-to-get-min-max)

Comment: I updated post with example of getting data-price value

Comment: @Michael, I provided a solution for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `map` method in combination with `Math.min` and `reduce` functions.

I used `reduce` method in order to find out the `sum` of the elements and get the `average` by divide the sum to the number of elements in `cars` array.

> The reduce() method applies a function against an accumulator and each
>   element in the array (from left to right) to reduce it to a single
>   value.

```
let prices = cars.map(function(element) {
   return element[0].getAttribute("data-price");
});

let lowestPrice = Math.min(...prices);
let avg = prices.reduce(function(acc, val) { return acc + val; }, 0)/prices.length
```

Alternative of `spread syntax`.

```
let lowestPrice = Math.min.apply(null, prices);
```

Comment: Thank you Mihai! What is the ... syntax? Is this supported on older browsers?

Comment: define "older browsers"

Comment: Hmm for some reason the avg is returning NaN

Comment: `undefined + <a number>` will do that.

Comment: @Michael, i updated my answer with an alternative for spread syntax.

Comment: `87.7891.2993.0293.0293.2594.0394.7294.8094.8095.74......` It continues, it's like 9000+ characters

Comment: Ah figured it out, I had to put Math.floor() around element[0].getAttribute("data-price")...It was in a string format

Comment: @Michael, don't forget to accept or vote answer in order to help other people.

Comment: @Michael, please have a look here how to accept and vote an answer: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work