# How to get lowest value from an element in Array / Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have the following Array

```
[
 0: {
  nameId: "041c1119"
  lastError: null
  spotId: "15808822"
  workType: "1"
 },
 1: {
  nameId: "041c1130"
  lastError: null
  spotId: "15808821"
  workType: "1"
 },
 2: {
  nameId: "041c11123"
  lastError: null
  spotId: "15808820"
  workType: "1"
 }
]
```

I'm trying to get the lowest `spotId` value, in this case I would need to get `15808820`.
I will appreciate any help of advice ( an example using lodash would be awesome)
Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Compare JavaScript Array of Objects to Get Min / Max](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8864430/compare-javascript-array-of-objects-to-get-min-max)

Comment: `arr.reduce((prev, curr) => prev.spotId < curr.spotId ? prev : curr).spotId`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need of any external library like Lodash, you can achieve the result in pure JS.

Here is the solution with one line code using ES6 features with [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) method.

```js
const data = [{
  nameId: "041c1119",
  lastError: null,
  spotId: "15808822",
  workType: "1"
}, {
  nameId: "041c1130",
  lastError: null,
  spotId: "15808821",
  workType: "1"
}, {
  nameId: "041c11123",
  lastError: null,
  spotId: "15808820",
  workType: "1"
}];


const minSpotId = data.reduce((prev, current) => (prev.spotId < current.spotId) ? prev : current);

console.log(minSpotId);
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend just iterating through the array and comparing to an existing min value:

```js
const data = [{
  nameId: "041c1119",
  lastError: null,
  spotId: "15808822",
  workType: "1"
}, {
  nameId: "041c1130",
  lastError: null,
  spotId: "15808821",
  workType: "1"
}, {
  nameId: "041c11123",
  lastError: null,
  spotId: "15808820",
  workType: "1"
}];

let minSpotId;

data.forEach(el => {
  if (minSpotId === undefined || parseInt(el.spotId) < minSpotId) {
    minSpotId = parseInt(el.spotId);
  }
});

console.log(minSpotId);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const data = [{
  nameId: "041c1119",
  lastError: null,
  spotId: "15808822",
  workType: "1"
}, {
  nameId: "041c1130",
  lastError: null,
  spotId: "15808821",
  workType: "1"
}, {
  nameId: "041c11123",
  lastError: null,
  spotId: "15808820",
  workType: "1"
}];

const lowest = Math.min.apply(Math, data.map(function(o) {
  return o.spotId
}));

console.log(lowest);
```