# find lowest and highest in array of object

Tags: javascript

I need to find 4 values in this order in a array of object:

- lowest x & y
- highest x and lowest y
- highest x & y
- highest y & lowest x

my object is like this :

```
   object: [
            {id: 1, x: 160, y: 160},
            {id: 2, x: 192, y: 160},
            {id: 3, x: 224, y: 160},
            {id: 4, x: 224, y: 192},
            {id: 5, x: 192, y: 192},
            {id: 6, x: 160, y: 192},
            {id: 7, x: 160, y: 224},
            {id: 8, x: 192, y: 224},
            {id: 9, x: 224, y: 224}
           ],
```

the result must be an array with those 4 object .

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by *"highest x and lowest y*"? What is this object for the given input?

Comment: [Compare JavaScript Array of Objects to Get Min / Max](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8864430)

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Because your description sounds *close* to having a bunch of points and wanting to find their bounding box...

Answer (score 0):

This is not the complete answer; `highest x and lowest y` and vice versa remained but it might give other contributors some insights how to solve the problem:

```js
const object = [
  {id: 9, x: 224, y: 224},
  {id: 2, x: 192, y: 160},
  {id: 3, x: 224, y: 160},
  {id: 4, x: 224, y: 192},
  {id: 5, x: 192, y: 192},
  {id: 6, x: 160, y: 192},
  {id: 7, x: 160, y: 224},
  {id: 8, x: 192, y: 224},
  {id: 1, x: 160, y: 160},
  {id: 9, x: 224, y: 224}
];
object.sort((objA, objB) => (objA.x * objA.y) - (objB.x * objB.y));
const HighestXAndHighestY = object[object.length-1];
const lowestXAndlowestY = object[0];
console.log(HighestXAndHighestY)
console.log(lowestXAndlowestY)
```