# get the lowest number using custom pipe in Angular 10

Tags: angular, angular-pipe

I made my custom pipe to get the lowest number in an array and came up with this simple code but it does not work.  It displays blank when rendered.

```js
@Pipe({
  name: 'min'
})
export class MinPipe implements PipeTransform {
    
  transform(items: any ): any {
    return Math.min.apply( Math, items );
  }   
}
```

I use it like this:

```html
<div *ngFor="let vars of variations"> 
     <div class="price-start">Starts at: {{vars.variationCost | min}}</div>
</div>
```

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: your pipe code is correct. check if you getting data in `vars.variationCost`

Comment: I am pretty sure the issue is the `apply`, is there a reason you're using that instead of directly calling `min`?

Comment: can you show a sample of 'variations' array?

Comment: a stackblitz would be even better

Comment: the apply is not the reason @DarioPiotrowicz,  

@ Kalimul the variations is pretty much the same with: variations = [
    { variationCost: 40 },
    { variationCost: 50 },
    { variationCost: 70 },
    { variationCost: 30 },
    { variationCost: 10 }
  ];

Comment: ah ok, I thought that could be the issue, sorry, my bad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure why you chose to delete the previous question that explained the issue better. At the moment the question is running into the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377).

Nevertheless, I presume from the previous question that you wish to filter the array based on the value held by the `variationCost` property. For that you could do a simple `*ngIf` inside the `*ngFor` as I suggested in the other question. If you want to use a pipe, it'd need to be applied to the `*ngFor` directive.

Try the following

**less-than.pipe.ts**

```js
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from "@angular/core";

@Pipe({ name: "lessThan", pure: true })
export class LessThanPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(collection: Array<any>, key: string, boundary: number): Array<any> {
    if (!collection) {
      return null;
    }

    return collection.filter(item => item[key] < boundary);
  }
}
```

Component

```js
import { Component } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  template: `
    <div *ngFor="let vars of (variations | lessThan: 'variationCost':45)">
      <div class="price-start">Starts at: {{ vars.variationCost }}</div>
    </div>
  `,
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent {
  variations = [
    { variationCost: 40 },
    { variationCost: 50 },
    { variationCost: 70 },
    { variationCost: 30 },
    { variationCost: 10 }
  ];
}
```

#### Update: Get minimum of object of array based on a property

To display only the minimum of the array, you don't really need the `*ngFor` directive. You could whip up a quick pipe and use it in conjunction with `*ngIf` directive.

Try the following

**min.pipe.ts**

```js
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from "@angular/core";

@Pipe({ name: "min", pure: true })
export class MinPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(collection: Array<any>, key: string): Array<any> {
    if (!collection) {
      return null;
    }

    // credit: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31844649/6513921
    return collection.reduce((acc, curr) =>
      acc[key] < curr[key] ? acc : curr
    );
  }
}
```

Template

```html
<div *ngIf="(variations | min: 'variationCost') as minVar">
  <div class="price-start">Starts at: {{ minVar.variationCost }}</div>
</div>
```

Working example: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-tuntzc?file=src/app/min.pipe.ts)

Comment: Sorry about that. 

I tried your code and it did work but it only filters the numbers that is less than "45". It show the numbers 30 & 10. What I wanted to achieve to show only is the number 10 which is the lowest number.