# Problem with array of objects in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

this is my first question here so I'll try to be precise as much as possible.

I have homework which requires me to create an array of 5 objects which are students with their name, surname and average grade.

The average grade being set as any number from `2` to `5` for example: `2.50`, `3.34`, `4.95` etc. My only job here is to **print out into the console the `name` and `surname` of the student with the lowest average grade.**

For the life of me I couldn't figure out how to do it and googling didn't help or at least **I didn't know how to look for it.**

I could only define the objects but I don't know how to list through the objects and find the lowest 'avgGrade'.

```js
var students = [
  { name: "John", surname: "Doe", avgGrade: 5.0 },
  { name: "Mike", surname: "Adams", avgGrade: 4.2 },
  { name: "Mark", surname: "Davis", avgGrade: 2.1 },
  { name: "Jane", surname: "Jones", avgGrade: 3.99 },
  { name: "Sarah", surname: "Quinn", avgGrade: 2.8 },
];
```

Comment: It's an array of objects. So you can step through it with a for-loop or you can use the array's `forEach` method.

Comment: [Compare JavaScript Array of Objects to Get Min / Max](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8864430/compare-javascript-array-of-objects-to-get-min-max)

Comment: Check out `for...of`, where you can loop through an array in a simple way: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can do this using a [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) loop,

We can declare two variables `lowestAvg`, which keeps track of the lowest average grade we have seen so far. And `lowestStudent`, which keeps track of the student that owns that grade.

We go through each student using a `for...of` loop checking their grade against the lowest that we've seen so far.

**Full code:**

```js
let students = [ { name: "John", surname: "Doe", avgGrade: 5.0 }, { name: "Mike", surname: "Adams", avgGrade: 4.2 }, { name: "Mark", surname: "Davis", avgGrade: 2.1 }, { name: "Jane", surname: "Jones", avgGrade: 3.99 }, { name: "Sarah", surname: "Quinn", avgGrade: 2.8 }, ];

let lowestAvg = 10;
let lowestStudent = null;

for (let student of students) {
  if (student.avgGrade <= lowestAvg) {
    lowestStudent = student;
    lowestAvg = student.avgGrade;
  } 
}

console.log(lowestStudent);
console.log(lowestStudent.name, lowestStudent.surname);
```